Unable to get Sliding Graph Effect in HighChart.js using React
I am trying to build a Line Chart for my React application. I want to get a sliding window effect in the line chart. I tried the following code but the graph doesn't slide on the x-axis. I get the data which i want to update from an api call and share the data using react context.
function ChartTest() {
  const data = useContext(DataContext);
  const [labels, setLabels] = useState([]);
  const [energyCost, setEnergyCost] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (Object.keys(data).length > 0) {
      const newData = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => ({
        y: value.Total
      }));
      const newLabels = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => Date.parse(value.Time));
      setEnergyCost(newData);
      setLabels(newLabels)
    }
  }, [data]);

  const options = useMemo(() => ({
    chart: {
      type: 'area',
      events: {
        load: function () {
          var series = this.series[0];
          let i = 0;
          setInterval(function () {
            if (i < energyCost.length) {
              var x =  labels[i],
                  y = energyCost[i];
              series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
              i++;
            }
          }, 1000);
        }
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
    },
    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: '{series.name} produced <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>warheads in {point.x}'
    },
    plotOptions: {
      area: {
        pointStart: 1940,
        marker: {
          enabled: false,
          symbol: 'circle',
          radius: 1,
          states: {
            hover: {
              enabled: true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Energy Cost',
      data: energyCost
    }]
  }), [energyCost]);

  return (
    <HighchartsReact
     highcharts={Highcharts}
     options={options}
    />
  )
}

export default ChartTest;

I tried to create an array to slice the data but that doesn't work. Maybe I did it wrong. I am a bit new to JavaScript. Is there any way to fix it ?
